# Embedding Python on Windows: why does it have to be a DLL?

Tags: python, windows, dll

I'm trying to write a software plug-in that embeds Python. On Windows the plug-in is technically a DLL (this may be relevant). The [Python Windows FAQ](http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html) says:

> 1.Do *not* build Python into your .exe file directly. On Windows, Python must be a DLL to handle importing modules that are themselves DLL’s. (This is the first key undocumented fact.) Instead, link to pythonNN.dll; it is typically installed in C:\Windows\System. NN is the Python version, a number such as “23” for Python 2.3.

My question is why exactly Python must be a DLL? If, as in my case, the host application is not an .exe, but also a DLL, could I build Python into it? Or, perhaps, this note means that third-party C extensions rely on `pythonN.N.dll` to be present and other DLL won't do? Assuming that I'd *really* want to have a single DLL, what should I do?

I see there's the `dynload_win.c` file, which appears to be the module to import C extensions on Windows and, as far as I can see, it scans the extension file to find which `pythonX.X.dll` it imports; but I'm not experienced with Windows and I don't quite understand all the code there.

Answer (score 4):

You need to link to `pythonXY.dll` as a DLL, instead of linking the relevant code directly into your executable, because otherwise the Python runtime can't load *other* DLLs (the extension modules it relies on.) If you make your own DLL you could theoretically link all the Python code in that DLL directly, since it doesn't end up in the executable but still in a DLL. You'll have to take care to do the linking correctly, however, as pretty much none of the standard tools (like distutils) will do this for you.

However, regardless of how you embed Python, you can't make do with *just* the DLL, nor can you make do with just any DLL. The ABI changes between Python versions, so if you compiled your code against Python 2.6, you need `python26.dll`; you can't use `python25.dll` or `python27.dll`. And Python isn't just a DLL; it also needs its standard library, which includes extension modules (which are DLLs themselves, although they have the `.pyd` extension.) The code in `dynload_win.c` you ran into is for loading *those* DLLs, and are not related to loading of `pythonXY.dll`.

In short, in order to embed Python in your plugin, you need to either ship Python with the plugin, or require that the right Python version is already installed.

Comment: What if I compile the standard library extensions myself and link them against my DLL (which would be made of my `foo` and `bar` and all objects that normally go into `pythonNN.dll` as I see in the `pythoncore` project)? In my case it's OK to have special versions of standard library or third-party extensions.

Comment: Then you still need all the rest of the standard library (all the .py files, and the .pyc and .pyo ones usually as well.) They are also Python-version specific. You can zip them up, but you can't avoid having them.

Comment: So basically, there's no way embed python in your application without bundling it with a python dll ?

Answer (score 2):

(Sorry, I did a stupid thing, I first wrote the question, and then registered, and now I cannot alter it or comment on the replies, because StackOverflow's engine doesn't think I'm the author. I cannot even properly thank those who replied :( So this is actually an update to the question and comments.)

Thanks for all the advice, it's very valuable. As far as I understand with some effort I can link Python statically into a custom DLL, provided that I compile other dynamically loaded extensions myself and link them against the same DLL. (I know I need to ship the standard library too; my plan was to append a zipped archive to the DLL file. As far as I understand, I will even be able to import pure Python modules from it.)

I also found an interesting place in `dynload_win.c`. (I understand it loads dynamic extensions that use Python C API, e.g. `_ctypes`.) As far as I can see it not only looks for `init_ctypes` symbol or whatever the extension name is, but also scans the `.pyd` file's import table looking for (regex) `python\d+\.` and then compares the found symbol with known `pythonNN.` string to make sure the extension was compiled for this version of Python. If the import table doesn't have such a symbol or it refers to another version, it raises an error.

For me it means that:

- If I link an extension against `pythonNN.dll` and try to load it from my custom DLL that includes a statically linked Python, it will pass the check, but — well, here I'm not sure: will it fail because there's no `pythonNN.dll` (i.e. even before getting to the check) or it will happily load the symbols?
- And if I link it against my custom DLL, it will find symbols, but won't pass the check :)

I guess I could rewrite this piece to suit my needs... Are there any other such places, I wonder.

Answer (score 1):

Python needs to be a dll (with a standard name) such that your application, and the plugin, can use the same instance of python.

Plugin dlls are already going to expect to be loading (and using python from) a python26.dll (or whichever version) - if your python is statically embedded in your exe, then two different instances of the python library would be managing the same data structures.

If the python libraries use no static variables at all, and the compile settings are *exactly* the same this should not be a problem. However, generally its far safer to simply ensure that only one instance of the python interpreter is being used.

Comment: My take:  If you look into a .pyd, such as _ctypes.pyd, you will see it references pythonxx.dll.  So it expects a pythonxx.dll to be around.  But if you have a static .lib, it won't be present.  In theory (??)  I guess one could have a companion pythonxx.dll so the imported modules would be happy, but I am not sure a module, if it loads, would work correctly.

Comment: Chris Becke, So it can be done if you have a python26.lib in your application and a python26.dll around so the imported module is happy?

Comment: The trick here is there are two kinds of .lib files: static library .lib files: One kind contain the full implementation, and the other kind just exist to tell MSVC how to link to a paired .dll file. The latter kind - which it sounds like you have - would work.

Comment: Chris Becke, I actually have the former fully implemented static .lib file (a pain to build...) If I also had the pythonxx.dll around, then I suppose the import would work, but would be using a different copy of the (same) library, which is prob. not a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

On *nix, all shared objects in a process, including the executable, contribute their exported names into a common pool; any of the shared objects can then pull any of the names from the pool and use them as they like. This allows e.g. `cStringIO.so` to pull the relevant Python library functions from the main executable when the Python library is statically-linked.

On Windows, each shared object has its own *independent* pool of names it can use. This means that it must read the relevant different shared objects it needs functions from. Since it is a lot of work to get all the names from the main executable, the Python functions are separated out into their own DLL.