# How to build Python into a C++ .exe

Tags: c++, python, embed

I have a c++ application and would like to take advantage of one of pythons libraries. I have seen info on how to run the python interpreter inside the program, however I want the program to be self-sufficient, so I can run it on any windows computer, even if it does not have python. How can i compile the python into the c++ .exe? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[You can't.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953039/embedding-python-on-windows-why-does-it-have-to-be-a-dll) You must have the DLL.

Comment: That doesn't mean he can't make his program work when Python is not installed. It just means that it comes with a .exe and a few DLLs.

Comment: Ok, well, how do i "have the dll"